# Twitter Bootstrap: Collapsable sidebar in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

This my have been asked already, so sorry for the redundancy (if any) — but I haven't figured out how to accomplish a collapsable sidebar using twitter bootstrap.

Using [this example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html), I'd like the sidebar to collapse like the global nav (header) on a mobile device.

Can someone link a code example or fiddle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8834859/1684247) - you could just adapt the show/hide behavior based on screen size/click events.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one or more of the following classes to the element you want to show or hide based on your screensize:

[image: Responsive utility classes]

```
...
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span3 hidden-phone">
...
```

- More [Info](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)
- Demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/MgcDU/2978/)

Answer (score 0):

## Try these ( both are best )

---

**Code**
https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-simple-

**Demo**
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar

---

**code** 
http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/facebook

**demo** 
http://www.bootply.com/render/96266

---